# Visual studio c++ force rebuild of a specific file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

Is there a way to force Visual studio to rebuild a specific file on every build?

I have a version header with `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` and I want it automatically updated for each release.

I can do a prebuild event and a batch file to `touch` the file, just wondered if there was a feature to do this yet?

Comment: If you change something in a header that other source files include, these will be rebuilt automatically? Where's the problem? I don't get it.

Comment: @LihO I think the point is that this particular header file has version information of sorts, so it has to be rebuilt regardless of whether any files were actually changed or not. (Which does progress to the question of whether the preprocessor, in replacing the `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` fields at compile-time, would mark the header as changed automatically. I think not.)

Comment: @LihO the `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` are automatically set to the current date/time by the compiler. But the compiler only processes the file if it thinks it has changed.

Comment: Ah, I get it now. Actually, it's a good question, you could just provide some code samples of how exactly you are using these `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` and how you are using (whatever you define in this header) it in other source files.

Answer (score 5):

You can also delete the `.obj` file with a pre-build step. It will cause the compiler to rebuild your `.cpp` or `.h` file. Right click your project > Properties > Build events > Pre-Build Event > Command Line and add the following line:

```
del $(TargetDir)source.obj
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've used it now. I think that should be $(IntDir) though, perhaps for you that's just the same as $(TargetDir).

Comment: del  "$(IntDir)source.obj" it is better to enclose in quotes in case directory path contains space.

Answer (score 4):

From [superuser](https://superuser.com/a/292663), try adding a prebuild command:

```
copy /b filename.ext +,,
```

Where `filename.ext` is the path/name of the header you want touched.  Caveat: I'm not certain VStudio always executes prebuild events, or only if it detects it actually needs to do a build.

Comment: I never knew copy had that flag. I was using `touch` from the unixutils and prebuild. I just thought it should be a feature that VS supported

Comment: I didn't know about it, either. Just googled for a windows equivalent to *nix's "touch" command.

Comment: Also, I'm curious if this will actually work for your situation (note my caveat).  Please let me know if it does.

Comment: No it doesn't run `post` (or even `pre` ) build if it doesn't think any files have changed

Answer (score 0):

There is a touch ms build task.  Add it to the build depends on target. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37fwbyt5.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this question using with the exact same underlying reason of wanting to always update `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` macros on build. No single answer here worked for me, but they were a great help.

As @Martin-Beckett mentioned in a comment, even `pre` build events won't run if nothing is perceived as having changed. The key is adding a **`post`** event to modify the file of interest. Then every time you hit `Build` it will be guaranteed to recompile that file as it will have changed after the last compilation.

Both the `del $(IntDir)file.obj` and `copy /b file.h +,,` methods worked for me. I'm partial to the copy, so for a step-by-step process:

- Right-click project -> `Properties` -> `Build Events` -> `Post-Build Event` > `Command Line` and add the following line:

  `copy /b file.h +,,`

I would recommend adding a `Description` for this as it comes up in the Build Output window. Now I can hit `Build` ten times in a row and that file is recompiled every time.